# Getlist with html form and store it in database SQLalchemy Flask Python

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I try to get the list of values from HTML form with Flask and store it in the Column in the database. I tried to use getlist() but I do not know how I should do that in a proper way.

Database:

```
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('book_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Book.id')),
    Column('form_id', Integer, ForeignKey('Form.id'))
    )

class Book(Base):
__tablename__ = 'Book'
name = Column(String(80), nullable = False, unique=True)
id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
author = Column(String(30))
language = Column(String(30))
category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Category.id'), nullable = False)
category = relationship(Category)
forms = relationship("Form", secondary=association_table, back_populates="books")

def __repr__(self):
    return '<Book %r>' % self.name
class Form(Base):
__tablename__ = 'Form'
name = Column(String, nullable = False)
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
books = relationship("Book", secondary=association_table, back_populates="forms")

def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

NEW BOOK Template:

```
<p>Choose Form</p>
<select name=form method="GET" action="/" multiple> 
{% for form in forms %}
<option value= "{{form}}" SELECTED>{{ form }}</option>"
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Route:

```
@app.route('/books/new/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newBook():
    categories = session.query(Category).all()
    forms = session.query(Form).all()
    #languages = session.query(Languages).all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newBook = Book(name = request.form['name'], 
                        author = request.form['author'], 
                        category = Category(name=request.form.get('category')),
                        forms = Form(name=request.form.getlist('form')),
                        language = request.form['language'])
        session.add(newBook)
        session.commit()
        flash("New Book Added!")
        return redirect(url_for('showBooks'))
    else:
        return render_template('newBook.html', languages=languages, categories=categories, forms=forms)
```

When I trying to add the new book I get TypeError:
Incompatible collection type: Form is not list-like

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `Book` instance, You should pass a list of `Form` instance to the constructor of `Book`.

```
book = Book(name=request.form["name"],
            author=request.form["author"],
            language=request.form["language"],
            category=request.form["category"],
            forms=[Form(name) for name in request.form.getlist("form")])
```

Comment: Thank You, but when I changed to   
forms=[Form(name) for name in request.form.getlist("form")])
I got TypeError TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
So I changed code to:
forms=[Form(name) for name in request.form.getlist("form[]")])
Now there is no errors but it still won't storred any strings in a list.

Comment: You should define constructor of Form which take name as parameter.

Comment: Still, have the problem. After adding 
def __init__(self, name):
self.name = name 
and tried to add New Book with Form=Paperback 
I now got  TypeError: Ebook is not JSON serializable
I didn't use JSON before in this project. Is it any different way to add that values to the list?

Comment: Can you update your question to include the whole traceback of the TypeError? I think this TypeError is not about current question.